# How to effectively unpack this type of structure and create a DataFrame?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

While generating x and y coordinates using

```
import networkx as nx
nx.fruchterman_reingold_layout()
```

I am left with this type of data structure:

```
{'SomeKey': array([value1,  value2]),
'SomeOtherKey': array([value1, value2])}
```

I have already tried code such as:

```
empty_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Person", "x", "y"])

list_of_keys = list(fruchterman.keys())

for key in list_of_keys:
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame({"Person": key, "x": [fruchterman[key][0]], "y": [fruchterman[key][1]]})
    for_later_save.append(dataframe, ignore_index=True)
```

I am either getting an error that says that I provide wrong index for a scalar value or an empty DataFrame:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Person, x, y]
Index: []
```

Trying a different approach is also ineffective:

```
Exception has occurred: IndexError
invalid index to scalar variable.
  File "Y:\Directory1\Directory2\Directory3\calculations.py", line 75, in <module>
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame({"Person": key, "x": [fruchterman[key][0][0]], "y": [fruchterman[key][0][1]]})
```

Comment: maybe use `print()` to see what values you have in variables. Maybe they are empty. It helps to see problem.

Comment: @KaszGG Does the answer solve the issue, or is there a further question?

Comment: @Trenton_M Was just testing the answer. It takes some time to process the data as I am working on a big dataset. It works perfectly.

Comment: Great, glad it worked.  I'm not affiliated with [RealPython](https://realpython.com/), but I reference them frequently, and they have a lot of great information you may find helpful in your endeavours.

Comment: @Trenton_M I know that website but sometimes while looking for a solve there's no time to read through a whole article which might be around something different and not really solve the problem. My first approach was more brute force just to loop through the dictionary and append. But I am glad that there's a bit simpler way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your data:

- [`pd.DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) should work to unpack `data`

### Data:

```py
data = {'SomeKey': array(['value1',  'value2']),
        'SomeOtherKey': array(['value1', 'value2'])}
```

### `orient='columns'`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='columns')
print(df)

  SomeKey SomeOtherKey
0  value1       value1
1  value2       value2
```

### `orient='index'`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.columns = ['Person', 'x', 'y']
print(df)

         Person       x       y
0       SomeKey  value1  value2
1  SomeOtherKey  value1  value2
```